Linearized or nonlinear least squares for Arrhenius: mitigating heteroscedasticity
I have a question that is essentially expanding on this older question, but digging into a specific aspect of it that was not directly discussed
Suppose I have data points that fit an Arrhenius trend:
$$y=Ae^{−\frac{E_A}{k_bT}}$$
I want to fit my dataset to this model, for which there are two main ways, which will yield different results:

direct nonlinear least-squares fitting
prior linearization of data, then linear regression via OLS

The answers to the question I link to are not very conclusive and mostly rely on what is standard practice. To me, it seems intuitive that the nonlinear fit is simply more truthful to the real physical data without unnecessary arbitrary transformation.
However, I want to ask if, in the case of marked heteroscedasticity (that is, if my error grows as the function grows), a linear fit would not be a good alternative. The reason for that is that if I fit directly on the nonlinear data, my results are going to be mostly decided by the high-temperature points, because the function values (and thus errors) are much larger there. The low-temperature values will play a comparatively unimportant role in the fitting process.
A linearized fit however, would present comparable errors across the whole curve, and the resulting fit could arguably be considered a better representation of the dataset as whole? It is a form of "built-in weighting scheme" so that every data point has a comparable importance.
Is there any discussion on the topic, and which kind of fitting to choose especially in the case where the error is not constant across temperatures?

This would be better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com. The answer depends on the sampling distribution for your data points. Probably the proper way to do it is to apply maximum likelihood estimation to data in the original form, $y=A \exp(- E_a/k_BT)$. If the data points are sampled with a normal distribution then this will be a weighted least squares (weighted by the standard deviation of the sampling distribution for each data point). If they are e.g. Poisson or binomial distributed you will need to apply maximum likelihood estimation generically. this question/answer may be of interest if you would like to learn more about maximum likelihood estimation.
I think it is not surprising that you get different answers depending on if you linearize the data or not. You are applying a non-linear transformation across the data, but not transforming the weighting similarly. By doing non-weighted (linear or non-linear) least squares you are likely biasing the fit results.

Ok, I see. The proper way to do this would be to weight each data point by the inverse of its variance in some sort of iterative weighted least squares method. Actually, the linearized fit seems to be sort of a poor man's version of that: although the residuals of the nonlinear fit show a clear trend, it is not the case for the linearized residuals (which suggests that no re-weighting would be necessary there). Seems that the linearization happens to rescale the errors in a somewhat similar way to a normalizing weighting scheme.

@BarbaudJulien what is the sampling distribution for the raw measured data?

This is not measured, but simulated data. The calculations being pretty heavy, I do not have easy access to information about the sampling distribution of each data point (obtaining a distribution for each data point would come at a considerable cost)

@BarbaudJulien yeah, so e.g. if you just have like one $y$ data point for each value of $T$ and you don't know the sampling distribution for that data point then it is not clear how you should fit the data. You can do unweighted least squares, but there's no guarantee the results will be the maximum likelihood estimator. And you won't be able to accurately calculate uncertainties on the fitted parameters. You can also do unweighted least squares on the linearized data set. It may or may not be more accurate depending on the unknown sampling distribution for the data points.
